# Toolbar Blue on iOS and Not Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to change the color of a toolbar in a Xamarin.Forms application. I used this to change the color:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new StartPage())
{
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#15315A"),
    BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#F3F9F5")
};
```

This works successfully on iOS, but on Android the Toolbar is just white. I tried to change the styles colors, and defined a `Toolbar.axml` with no luck either. I posted the pictures below of what I am seeing. Anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change it from `Resources`->`values`->`styles.xml` in your Android project. Set the `colorPrimaryDark` value to `#15315A`.

Answer (score 0):

There was a fairly good answer on this post on the [xamarin developer forums.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17811/tabbedpage-tabbar-background-color-tint) Basically there's a couple of options to get this to work, these are:

An [Appearance](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_the_appearance_api/) which works globally.

Or using a custom renderer.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(TabbedPageCustom))]
namespace MobileCRM.iOS 
{     
    public class TabbedPageCustom : TabbedRenderer      
    {         
        public TabbedPageCustom ()         
        {             
            TabBar.TintColor = MonoTouch.UIKit.UIColor.Black;             
            TabBar.BarTintColor = MonoTouch.UIKit.UIColor.Blue;             
            TabBar.BackgroundColor = MonoTouch.UIKit.UIColor.Green;         
        }     
    } 
}
```